# LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE cause WebView load blank page

Tags: android, webview

I put a webview into the scrollview and set its layer type to LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE. However this caused my webview loaded a blank page as result if the html content was too much. I have to set the layer type to NONE but this will cause a serious GPU Overdraw. Is there any way I can do to solve this problem?

Comment: how do you set the LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE in iOS Swift 4.0